# Read Bundle version and Bundle versions string from Phonegapp Application for iPad

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

In Xcode we can specify Bundle version and Bundle versions string for an iOS application and we can read values associated with it using native coding.

I want to achieve the same functionality for cross-platform application. I'm currently working on Phonegap application and I want to read above values. Any ideas how can I do it?

With the help of [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/index.html) I know using device.version from phonegap api we can get OS version, no more additional information is available.

Appreciate if any document is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a plugin for getting CFBundleName, CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/my-phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/AppInfo